# Should you separate users and usersList in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm fairly new to Node.js and Express and I'm currently building the server after building most of the frontend (React) of a complex app.
In the app I separated the mock data in users and usersList because I did not want the API calls to be too heavy to only render the list of users with all the details that each user include.
My usersList schema is as such:

```
const usersListSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
   }
```

while my user schema is:

```
const usersSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    ... 20 other properties
   }
```

Now my question is:
Is it the right way and if yes, when I will create a new user will I need to POST on 2 url ("url/user-list" & "url/user" for exemple) or is there another way to achieve this in on POST request.

Thank you

Comment: This is not the right way. It's better you only have one schema for the users and only manipulate the database based on that one schema whether you are dealing with url/user or url/user-list. The list of users and the users are practically the same thing, wrong to have 2 different schemas for them.

Comment: On the `url/user-list/get` route, for example (if you have one), you can select all the users in the users collection and return it as an array, fulfilling the function of that route. There's no real need to have a separate schema for this, it's just one extra thing to manage for no reason, unless you can specify why you exactly need it.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan so kind of a follow up question, each user has a conversation and image (that can be very very big) I planned on have a imageId and conversationId in the schema to make an API call such as url/image/:id is it a good method or should I stay on yours and call the specific point of the schema based on the situation?

Comment: In regards to the conversations, have a separate schema for them where you link the conversation with the user by having a userId property/field that stores in the id of the particular user that conversation belongs to.

About the image, no need for a separate schema NOR for storing it directly in the database. With medium-large file uploads, it is much recommended that you upload your files to a directory on the server and then save the path / server API URL of that file into the database as a string. When you need access to the file, you simply get its path / URL and load from the server.

Comment: So, what I suggest is that you have a property/field in the users schema that is a string field for the image, and then have the images from the app be uploaded inside an actual directory that is accessible by an HTTP request. Like, a static directory that is enabled by express. Then you store the URL / name of the file in that field as a string and fetch it whenever needed by that name. It is generally not very much recommended to store files in the database directly unless they are very small in size.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan perfect, you really answered everything in a very clear manner! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

you could use myUserSchema,
and when you want to fetch list of user with just firstName and lastName

with mongoose

```html
await UserList.
  find({}).
  select({ firstName: 1, lastName: 1 }).
  exec();
```

use 1 if you want to select value with same name as your attribute

Comment: Thank you, but is it the best way to do it? Like server wise will this operation be more, equal or less cost efficient than having 2 separate schema?

Comment: it depends, there is no one-size-fits-all answer..
split into 2 schemas makes it easier to do testing and improve maintainability

but if your document are not very large and you only need a few fields from them, feel free to use .select()

Comment: @CarvelSaputra I would request you to elaborate on how dividing it into 2 schemas should help with testing. Anyway, I believe the question is opinion-based (As it is more about whether a specific practice is good or not that can have multiple conflicting answers.) so I've voted to close it.